# Create Instance of different Object Based on parameter passed to function using C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have base class FactoryBO which has a method to create Instance of different object.

```
public class FactoryBO
{
    //ctor
    public FactoryBO()
    {
    }

    public T CreateObject<T>(string BusinessObjectName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessObjectName))
            return default(T);

        object valueObj = null;

        switch (BusinessObjectName.ToLower())
        {
           case "temporary registration": { valueObj = new TemporaryDriverRegistrationBO(); break; }
            case "driver registration": { valueObj = new TemporaryDriverRegistrationBO(); break; }            }

        return (T)valueObj;
    }

    public virtual SqlParameter[] GenerateQuery(params object[] StoredProcedureParameters)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

There are 2 derived class from FactoryBO, which overrides the virtual method in FactoryBO.

```
public class TemporaryDriverRegistrationBO : FactoryBO
{
    public override SqlParameter[] GenerateQuery(params object[] StoredProcedureParameters)
    {
         //some Code
    }
}

 public class DriverRegistrationBO : FactoryBO
 {
      public override SqlParameter[] GenerateQuery(params object[] StoredProcedureParameters)
    {
         //some Code
    }
 }
```

Now If I execute below code it gives me object of  "TemporaryDriverRegistrationBO"

```
   object fbo = new FactoryBO().CreateObject<object>("temporary registration");
   SqlParameter[]  xx = ((FactoryBO)(fbo)).GenerateQuery()
```

**I am doing it in wrong way? Does this follow any design pattern?**

***What would be the correct way of doing about functionality?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation you are not limiting user of your code with what to pass as `T`. That sounds like an issue, consider using following type parameter limitation `where T: FactoryBo, new()`.
Yet that isn't what you look for. What I'd suggest is creating a dictionary of functions mapping certain business object name to the constructor of appropriate class:

```
public class FactoryBO
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Func<FactoryBO>> objects =
                new Dictionary<string, Func<FactoryBO>>
                    {
                            {"temporary registration", () => new TemporaryDriverRegistrationBO()},
                            {"driver registration", () => new DriverRegistrationBO()}
                    };

        public static FactoryBO CreateObject(string businessObjectName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(businessObjectName))
            {
                return new FactoryBO();
            }

            Func<FactoryBO> objectCtor = null;
            objects.TryGetValue(businessObjectName.ToLower(), out objectCtor);

            return objectCtor != null ? objectCtor() : new FactoryBO();
        }

        public virtual SqlParameter[] GenerateQuery(params object[] StoredProcedureParameters)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In my implementation I'm returning an instance of base class - `FactoryBO` in case the entry is not found in the dictionary. That's a bit different from your behaviour where you return `default(T)` for empty string parameter(this returns `null` for reference types).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But if this code is used while making a website and if multiple number of user are there. Then every user will get the same instance of TemporaryDriverRegistrationBO or DriverRegistrationBO since it is static. IF I remove static then "objects" will hold list of object even if it is not required.  --- Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are more than confused here. The dictionary itself doesn't contain references to object instances, instead it has a reference to the delegate function that will create an object for you. That said, new instance each time.

Answer (score 0):

In your switch, you return types, not instances of these types.

Replace:

```
switch (BusinessObjectName.ToLower())
{
    case "temporary registration": { valueObj = typeof(TemporaryDriverRegistrationBO); break; }
    case "driver registration": { valueObj = typeof(DriverRegistrationBO); break; }
}
```

With:

```
switch (BusinessObjectName.ToLower())
{
    case "temporary registration":
        valueObj = new TemporaryDriverRegistrationBO();
        break;
    case "driver registration": 
        valueObj = new DriverRegistrationBO();
        break;
}
```

Assuming that your objects have default constructors.

Anyway, your generic parameter is useless here, and your created objects don't have to extend `FactoryBO`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a valid use of generics. It looks like what you really want is polymorphism, and you don't need generics to take advantage of polymorphism.

Give this a try (note that I've made the method static because it doesn't use any instance variables):

```
public static FactoryBO Create(string BusinessObjectName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessObjectName))
    {
        return null;
    }

    FactoryBO valueObj = null;

    switch (BusinessObjectName.ToLower())
    {
        case "temporary registration": 
           valueObj = new TemporaryDriverRegistrationBO(); 
           break;
        case "driver registration": 
           valueObj = new DriverRegistrationBO(); 
           break;
    }

    return valueObj;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
FactoryBO fbo = FactoryBO.Create("temporary registration");
```