# Create an empty constructor when wrong parameters

Tags: java

```
class classname {
private int value;

    public classname(int value) {

            if(value > 20 || value < 1) {
                //make object null 
            }
            else {
                this.value = value;
            }

    }
}
```

Basically, when the parameter is not in the range I want to make an empty object.

something like:

```
classname newclass = new classname(100);

if(newclass == null) {
//this is what i want
}
```

Comment: A constructor cannot "return" null. You can create a function that returns either a valid object or null.

Comment: first off, you can't do exactly what you are asking (which is a good thing!)

also, using null to represent an optional value is an [anti-pattern](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html).

Take a look at using [optionals](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html).

if you can't use java 8, the [google guava lib has optionals too](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)

Comment: I know it can't, I want to create: (classname)null instance

Answer (score 2):

Instead of initialising an `object` with `null`, you should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, e.g.:

```
if(value > 20 || value < 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be between 1 and 20");
}
```

This would prevent the initialisation and return correct error message to the user. Also, this is considered as best practice (e.g. try calling `Integer.parseInt("abc");`)

Comment: That's what I did, but i have tests that I have to fulfill which does not throw an exception. When this happens they have to go through Assert.assertNull("you can't create that bro",newclass);

Comment: You can change the tests if that's in your control. It's always better to detect and throw and error when you know something is not what it should be, than to return `null` and let something else fail unexpectedly down the line.

Answer (score 1):

For this look at factory design. You should create a factory class and let that factory return the class instance. Inside factory implementation you can write the logic based on parameter.

Look at this post.
[Create Instance of different Object Based on parameter passed to function using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402117/create-instance-of-different-object-based-on-parameter-passed-to-function-using)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a factory method which either return instance if argument is valid or null and hide the constructor using `private`:

```
class YourClass {
    private int value;

    // Factory method
    public static YourClass newYourClass(int value) {
        if(value > 20 || value < 1)
            return null;
        else
            return new YourClass(value);
    }

    private YourClass(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do somthing like this

```
class classname {
        private Integer value;

        public classname(Integer value) {
          this.value = value <1 || value>20 ? null : value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't just assign null to integer.

Comment: Uuse Integer  class instead of primitive : Integer value ; and then 
you can assign it to null :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in this way

```
public class MyClass {

    private int value; // if -1 not in the range!

    public MyClass(int value) {

        if (value > 20 || value < 1) {
            this.value = -1;
        } else {
            this.value = value;
        }
    } //end of constructor

 } //end of the MyClass
```

Comment: While this is one way to indicate a value is not correctly provided, a far better and Java-like approach would be using a `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomObjectFactory
{
  private int value;
  CustomObjectFactory(int value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public CustomObjectFactory getInstance()
  {
    System.out.print(value);
    if(value<10)
    {
      System.out.print("if"+value);
      return null;
    }else
    {
      System.out.print("else"+value);
      return new CustomObjectFactory(value);
    }
  }

}
```